# Kendo TreeView how to choose template(s) based on Authorization in Jquery

Tags: kendo-treeview

Kendo TreeView how to choose template(s) based on Authorization in Jquery

I have a kendo TreeView that has AuthorizationFlag(Y or N) that decides whether to use Template1 or Template2. How do I achieve this.
For example If I get response as Y then I should load the template1 or else Template2

```
<script id="template1" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
If Auth is Success
</script>

<script id="template2" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
If Auth is fail
</script>
```

Comment: You can provide a if/else flag in your template and pass the flag (Y or N) through your view model

Answer (score 0):

I would do like Harsha pps sugested!

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="myTemplate">
    #if(task.Auth== 'Y'){#
        <div>If Auth is Success</div>
    #}else{#
        <div>If Auth is fail</div>
    #}#
</script>
```

Where I assume that the authorization Y/N is in the variable Auth

Please check Teleriks [example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/gantt-tooltip-based-on-custom-field)!